# Merging/Updating data sets in Python or Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I just started learning python to help me work more efficiently with data files at work instead of just using excel. One issue I constantly have is I often need to download csv files from our database and start cleaning, coding, and formatting the data. However, often there is data missing or data gets updated in the database so then I need to update my data that I already started cleaning in excel. I usually have to copy and paste the new data into my excel file and as you can guess that is not very efficient. Is there a more time effective way to update my original data with the new data using python or pandas?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas, what you can do is create a new pandas.DataFrame with the new data, process it the same is with the previous data and then merge both using `pandas.concat()` to join them just one below the other or `pandas.merge()` if you want to join them by an specific column to update rows that were present previously.

[pandas.concat doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Example:

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

[pandas.merge doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Example:

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='<identifier>')
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into those. But lets say I have random blank cells throughout my original data set, is there a way to fill in those blank cells with the data from the new data set without merging the whole column? Like just merge the data that is missing if that makes sense?

Comment: The short answer to that question is maybe, if you know the index of the column you want to add that data you could make an ```pandas.insert(...)``` , but you would have to iterate through each row you want to insert because this method only inserts one row at a time. You can check the documentation in case it's useful.
[pandas.insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

If I was useful answering your questions, please don't forget to vote this answer as useful :)